# function call returning result continuous number of times

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def foo(bar):
    def looger():
        print 'hello from first satatement'
        parent()
        print 'hello from second satatement'
    return looger
def parent():
   print 'printing from parent function'
parent = foo('hi')
parent()
```

i have got stuck with a problem. the code above is returning result *hello from first statement* continuous times and then showing error . i got to know the error that parent function is not correctly called , but i don't understand why this is giving me continuous result .

Comment: start by fixing your indentation - its important

Comment: As you seems to be starting with Python, le me suggest you to use the last Python 3 version rather than so soon to be depreciated 2.7 version.

Comment: @Delgan I wonder when Debian will move to Python3. I doubt Python 2 will disappear soon.

Answer (score 2):

You are accidentally creating infinite recursion by overwriting the global function parent with the returned logger function:

```
def foo(bar):
    def looger():
        print('hello from first satatement')
        parent() # This calls ....
        print('hello from second satatement')
    return looger
def parent():
   print('printing from parent function')
parent = foo('hi') # this function, what is not what you want
parent()
```

You can fix this by renaming the returned function:

```
def foo(bar):
    def looger():
        print('hello from first satatement')
        parent()
        print('hello from second satatement')
    return looger
def parent():
   print('printing from parent function')
p = foo('hi')
p()
```

prints:

```
hello from first satatement
printing from parent function
hello from second satatement
```